# Integrating Paypal SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal, payment-gateway

I'm trying to integrate the `PayPal sdk` for `iOS` app. I have installed it through `Cocoapods` ... Now I want to link some of the binary files .Should I have to download them and add manually or what is the case? Please let me know the steps to do so...

Thank you...

Comment: Please find tutorials in Google.

Comment: Yes I have gone through such...but my question is whether we have to link those binary libraries by manually unzipping them or how?

Comment: If you install libraries via Cocoapods, you don't need to download other files. Just open the Xcode workspace file & Build the App.

Comment: Yes,but i'm getting an linker error for libary  -lPayPalMobile ...

Comment: Make sure you open the Workspace instead of Project. Also make sure you're using the latest version of Cocoapods. What Xcode version are you using?

Comment: @Raptor: I'm using Xcode 6.4 but my OS has been upgraded to 10.11(El Capitan). and the PayPal SDK which I'm trying to install through cocoapods is 2.11.2

Answer (score 2):

Follow the below code:-

```
#import "PayPalMobile.h"

@property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) PayPalConfiguration *payPalConfig;
@property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSString *environment;
```

Implement the delegates

```
<PayPalPaymentDelegate, PayPalFuturePaymentDelegate>
```

Call the below method named configPaypalPayment and implement the delegate methods as follows:-

```
#pragma mark - paypal

- (void)configPaypalPayment {

  _environment = PayPalEnvironmentSandbox;

  [PayPalMobile preconnectWithEnvironment:_environment];

  // Set up payPalConfig

  _payPalConfig = [[PayPalConfiguration alloc] init];
  _payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = YES;
  _payPalConfig.merchantName = @"Andmine";
_payPalConfig.merchantPrivacyPolicyURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/privacy-full&#8221"];
    _payPalConfig.merchantUserAgreementURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/useragreement-full&#8221"];
   _payPalConfig.languageOrLocale = [NSLocale preferredLanguages][0];
   _payPalConfig.payPalShippingAddressOption = PayPalShippingAddressOptionNone;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark PayPalPaymentDelegate methods

- (void)payPalPaymentViewController:
            (PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController
                 didCompletePayment:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
  NSLog(@"PayPal Payment Success!");

  [self sendCompletedPaymentToServer:completedPayment]; // Payment was processed
                                                        // successfully; send to
                                                        // server for
                                                        // verification and
                                                        // fulfillment
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)payPalPaymentDidCancel:
    (PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController {
  NSLog(@"PayPal Payment Canceled");
  //  self.resultText = nil;
  //  self.successView.hidden = YES;
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark Proof of payment validation

- (void)sendCompletedPaymentToServer:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
  // TODO: Send completedPayment.confirmation to server
  NSLog(@"Here is your proof of payment:\n\n%@\n\nSend this to your server for "
        @"confirmation and fulfillment.",
        completedPayment.confirmation);
}

#pragma mark - Authorize Future Payments

- (IBAction)getUserAuthorizationForFuturePayments:(id)sender {

  PayPalFuturePaymentViewController *futurePaymentViewController =
      [[PayPalFuturePaymentViewController alloc]
          initWithConfiguration:self.payPalConfig
                       delegate:self];
  [self presentViewController:futurePaymentViewController
                     animated:YES
                   completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark PayPalFuturePaymentDelegate methods

- (void)payPalFuturePaymentViewController:
            (PayPalFuturePaymentViewController *)futurePaymentViewController
                didAuthorizeFuturePayment:
                    (NSDictionary *)futurePaymentAuthorization {
  NSLog(@"PayPal Future Payment Authorization Success!");
//  self.resultText = [futurePaymentAuthorization description];
//  [self showSuccess];

  [self sendFuturePaymentAuthorizationToServer:futurePaymentAuthorization];
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)payPalFuturePaymentDidCancel:
    (PayPalFuturePaymentViewController *)futurePaymentViewController {
  NSLog(@"PayPal Future Payment Authorization Canceled");
//  self.successView.hidden = YES;
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)sendFuturePaymentAuthorizationToServer:(NSDictionary *)authorization {
  // TODO: Send authorization to server
  NSLog(@"Here is your authorization:\n\n%@\n\nSend this to your server to "
        @"complete future payment setup.",
        authorization);
}
```

Comment: Thank you...since i'm new to iOS I want to ask you that, for example i have a button action to place a certain order and check out the product , so do i have to create a new viewcontroller class and implement these methods?

Comment: For this, you don't need to create a new viewController. On your checkout viewController, call the above payPal method. It will automatically pop the payPal view and return the result.